# Is it bad practice to return a generic inside an abstract class of different generic parameter

Tags: java, class, generics

I have this abstract class where I have defined some methods that implement database actions (fetch rows, insert, delete, etc.)

Now I want to make method that will return some rows (i.e. the whole table) but instead of the domain classes I want it to return the corresponding model classes (which basically is the same as domain but without the relationship lists and some other stuff I don't need for the presentation layer).

The abstract class is

```
public abstract class DomainService<T extends Domain> {

    protected abstract Logger getLogger();

    protected final Validator validator;

    protected DomainService() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        this.validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    abstract public void insert(T object) throws ValidationException;

    abstract public void delete(T object) throws EntityNotFoundException;

    abstract public List<T> fetchAll();
}
```

and I want to add another method that will call `fetchAll()` and then iterate each item and create the model equivalent and return *that* list.

```
public <K extends  Model> List<K> fetchAllModels(Class<K> modelClass) {
        List<T> domains = fetchAll();
        List<K> models = new ArrayList<K>(domains.size());

        for ( T domain : domains) {
            K model = modelClass.newInstance();
            models.add(model.fillIn(domain));
        }

        return models;
    }
```

Disregarding that this is the code I though just now writing the question, is it acceptable to add a parameter for a generic that is not defined in the class. IMO a class can have methods returning other data types so it should not be a problem. In my case I pass the class so I can create an instance of the model and then use the domain to fill the members. I was of two opinions,

- The one I wrote where I add a method to the model class to create it self from the domain object. I was thinking of a constructor that takes the domain object as an argument, but I think it's a bit of a hassle to call a constructor using generics (It would need reflection utilities at the very least) so I though of a method to fill the details after creating an instance using the default constructor. Also the model is on a higher layer and I think higher layers should use lower ones (Database->Domain classes->Access classes (DAO)->Service classes->Servlet classes----> JSP showing data)
- I could add a method to the domain class that transforms the domain to its model and call that without having to pass the class of the model

  ```
  public <K> List<K> fetchAllModels() {
      List<T> domains = fetchAll();
      List<K> models = new ArrayList<K>(domains.size());

      for ( T domain : domains) {
          models.add(domain.createModel());
      }

      return models;
  }
  ```

but I feel that the domain class should be as clean a representation of the table in the database with the only methods having to do with the columns.

Would it better to add the parameter on the class. I am only going to use it for this method...

Any thoughts comments always welcome

Comment: Not sure if I got you, but yes; if you have type parameters that are only required for single methods; then you should actually do it like that - there is no need to make it a class wide parameter.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the option B cannot work because of type inference, how can Java compiler infer the type _K_ given only information on the type _T_?

Comment: Disregard the above, I confused the questions. K extends Model, which is the base abstract class. And domain#createModel returns the model type.

Comment: @AndreasAndreou then may be you should explicit that `<K extends Model>` ?

Comment: If _DomainService_ is a truly service (e.g: not a DAO), it should handle only Model (_K_) not the domain (_T_), the domain is an 'implementation' detail between him and his corresponding DAO.

Comment: @superbob I see what you mean... But then, you are suggesting that the service only returns models back to the servlets? So it will make calls to its corresponding DAO and get the domain object (or list of domain objects) and then go on and process them to create the corresponding model object (or list of models objects) and then return those further up?

Comment: @superbob What about my fillIn method? What's your thoughts on that?

Comment: @AndreasAndreou, Yes and for the _fillIn/createModel_ methods, I'm not fond if inserting _logic_ into _data_ objects (DTO, POJO, ...), because it mixes the concerns and doesn't respect the separation between model and domain. I prefer to either hand code the transformation into private methods in each concrete implementation or use a tool such as [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I will have to agree with you on the separation issue. In my defense this was something I just cooked up for the question but it shows that I still have to adjust my thinking a bit. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it acceptable to add a parameter for a generic that is not defined in the class

Absolutely. It's done all the time.

I prefer your first solution, passing the model to the method.

But, what you really want there is a function that creates K from T. In java8, this can be done very succinctly.

```
public <K extends  Model> List<K> fetchAllModels(Function<T,K> func) {
...
            K model = func.apply(domain);
```

and say you have a Model 'M' for domain 'D'

```
public M(D domain) // constructor
```

you can pass the constructor as `func` (or at least it seems so)

```
    service.fectchAllModels( M::new )
```

---

If you use `Stream`, `fetchAllModels()` becomes much simpler

```
abstract public Stream<T> fetchAll();

public <K extends  Model> Stream<K> fetchAllModels(Function<T,K> func) {
    return fetchAll().map(func)
}
```

And then, why do we even need this method? Just do

```
// fetch domains, convert each to M
Stream<M> models = service.fetchAll().map( M::new );
```

So we can remove `fetchAllModels()`, and remove any dependencies on model from domain.